# Deploy contract using solcjs

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm trying to deploy a contract using solcjs following that tutorial blog post https://blog.topl.me/how-to-deploy-solidity/

here is my code

```
const web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));


async function compileAndDeploy() {
    let ambrosiaContract;
    try {
        let contract = await fs.readFileSync( path.join(__dirname, './Ambrosia.sol') );
        let Ambrosia = contract.toString();
        let input = {};
        input[ path.join(__dirname, './Ambrosia.sol')] = Ambrosia;

        console.log('> Compiling Storage');
        let output = solc.compile({sources: input}, 1);

        console.log(output.contracts, output.formal);
        ambrosiaContract = output.contracts['Ambrosia'];
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    console.log('deploying...')
    let ambrosiaInstance = await deployStorage(ambrosiaContract)
    console.log('...deployed at ' + ambrosiaInstance.address)
}

compileAndDeploy();
```

now when I actually run the script, the compiler send me back that error.

> Error: Type "bytes32" not supported for state variable.\n    mapping
>   (address => bytes32) restaurants;\n

here is my contract code.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract Ambrosia {

    mapping (address => bytes32) restaurants;

    address _owner;

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value); // listen to that event whenever a transfer has been made..

    event Order(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value); // listen to that event whenever an order is triggered

    function Ambrosia() {
        _owner = msg.sender;
    }
}
```

I am using solcjs version 0.4.4
the error doesnt depend on the node client, it happen both with geth and js-eth on the development network

Answer (score 1):

This error is from Solidity [formal verification tool](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security-considerations.html#formal-verification). By now it does not support most of the Solidity's features, so you are free to ignore them.

Actual *compile* errors are returned in `output.errors` array. Try to add some typo and run this:

```
const output = solc.compile({sources: input}, 1);
console.log(output.errors);
```